# Tzitzit Knot Problem

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tallit-gadol, tallit-katan

I have noticed that sometimes the **knots** (not the strings) on a the tzitzit from a Tallit Katan or a Tallit Gadol either come or become tangled. Is it permissible to untie and then retie the tzitzit? I don't see a reason why it wouldn't be, but I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know(I am not a Rav): 
there is no problem, Moreover - if the first knot (that is near the talit) became loose the Tzizit might not be Kosher.
If you re-tie the first knot you should cocentrate "L'eshem Mitzvat Tzizit" since it is the "Mederoita"

Comment: Alaychem, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please note that there's no need to specify that you're not a Rav, as that is the assumption here on every single answer post. Unless you describe particular relevant expertise within your answer, there's no good reason for anyone to assume that you have any, any more than they would for any other random person on the street or the net. As a result, answer posts are much more worthwhile if they quote their sources than if they don't.

Comment: @Alaychem, anyone who is Jewish is allowed to tie tzitzit, although I believe that most poskim hold that tzitztiot tied by a woman are bediaved. It is according to many blurbs (without halachic authorities behind them) preferable for one to tie one's own tzitziot, as one will fulfill another mitzvah by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there should be any problem at all, but maybe you should remove the tallis or tallis katan while the tzitzis are untied, because having a length of 12 *gudalim* tied is required miD'rabbanan.

If you untie the second knot (i.e. the second of five double knots, starting from the hole) you definitely would have to remove the garment, because without a knot, some windings and a second knot you don't even have tzitzit *min HaTorah*, so you would be מבטל מצוות עשה if you are wearing it at that point.

If I'm not mistaken, the Gra holds that you can't say a bracha on tzitzis if they are tangled, so you would have to take care of the problem before putting on the tallis or tallis katan.